# Ambiguous redirect error when using cat with regex

Tags: redirect, ambiguous

I have a dir with files : X, A_1, A_2, A_3, etc..
I want to append X to A_1, A_2,A_3,.. and write to A_1,A_2,A_3,...
That is : cat X >> A_1, cat X >> A2, cat X >> A3

When I do

```
cat X >> A_*
```

I get

```
-bash: A_*: ambiguous redirect
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

While that would work in zsh with the `multios` option set, bash doesn't allow you to specify more than one redirect target per stream. You could do this with a loop, but your best option is to use `tee`.

```
cat X | tee -a A_* >/dev/null
```